# Username password login through external identity server

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

How can I use an external OAuth2 server to get a token with a local username/password challenge.

When I add an OAuth scheme, it shows up as a button, but I want it to use the username/password login and make a request to the identity server for the token.

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddOAuth("sso", "Single Sign-On", options =>
            {
                options.ClientSecret = "somesecret";
                options.ClientId = "someid";
                options.ClaimsIssuer = "https://identity.somewhere.net";
                options.CallbackPath = "/api/authentication/ExternalLoginBack";
                options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://identity.somewhere.net/authorize";
                options.TokenEndpoint = "https://identity.somewhere.net/oauth2/token";
                
            });
```

This causes a button to show up that says "Single Sign-on".  I don't want the button, I want the login button to pass the username/password challenge.

Green good.  Red bad.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading your question, but I think you misunderstand how authentication works with an external OAuth2 (OpenID) party. If you want the external party to perform the authentication, then you should not be handling the user's credentials but instead simply forward the user to login somewhere else and return with a valid token to you. That's what the "Single Sign-On" button is supposed to do.

Comment: @Xerillio Right.  I'm trying to create a login for that purpose.  Just a simple login page that is not on the identity server itself because the identity server is an old ASP.Net Identity server that we cannot upgrade so we just want to treat it like a dumb login interface for the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand the setup you have, but it's a little unclear to me, so I've sketched what I'm imagining your are aiming for:

```
 0. User accesses webpage
        |
 _______V_______                          ________________
|               |  1. Redirect for authn |                |
|  Application  | ---------------------> |  Old Identity  |
|   / website   |                        |     server     |
|     server    | <--------------------- |                |
|_______________|  4. Redirect user back |________________|
                      with a token           Λ       |
  5. Use token                               |       |
     to start                                |       |
     a session        3. Entered credentials |       | 2. Prompt user for
                         sent to the server  |       |    credentials
                         and verified        |       |
                                          ___|_______V____
                                         |                |
                                         |   User login   |
                                         |      page      |
                                         |________________|
```

For the application server to interact and forward the authentication management to the "old" identity server both servers need to implement support for OAuth2/OpenID Connect. This way the identity server can generate tokens that the application server trusts and that way let the identity server handle the authentication.

Now, it's clear to me if this identity server has a user interface or not, but I'm guessing here that it does (or can get one). So, when the user is redirected from the application server to the identity server, the identity server will request credentials from the user and verify those in its backend user store (database or whatever). If they are valid, the token is generated and the user is redirected back to the application which can now start an active session for the user.

I'm likely off on some points in regards to what you're looking for, so you'll have to elaborate on the setup you have, what you are able to do (you mention limitations for the identity server) and possibly how I'm off target.

Comment: Hmm.  I was thinking that the login page would be the one above, but that actually does make more sense.  I was hoping to backchannel the identity server.  So yeah.  I do want to provide a login for the identity server .... but on a remote server.